# OFFSET @SkipRecords ROWS FETCH NEXT @MaxRecords ROWS ONLY ignoring repeating ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big set of data that needs to be paginated. I am writing stored procedure that will have pagination with **@skip @take** params.

I have repeating IDs that when skipping or taking rows need to be processed as one row.

```
ID | Name | Value     | RowCounter
---+------+-------    +-----------
1  | A    | 10        | 1
1  | B    | 20        | 1
2  | C    | 30        | 2
3  | D    | 40        | 3
3  | E    | 50        | 3
3  | F    | 60        | 3
```

So if I will skip 0 take 2, it will take A, B, C rows, skip 1 take 2 will take C, D, E, F rows.

My query

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT leg.ID, 
  leg.IsTest, 
  leg.LegalEntityName,
  leg.PracticeNumber, 
  sfe.AccountNumber, 
  leg.LegalEntityID, 
  leg.ShouldRetryOnFailure, 
  leg.ResponseCode, 
  sub.SalesforceEntityID
FROM [dbo].[LegalEntity] leg
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SubMerchant] sub ON sub.LegalEntityID = leg.ID AND sub.SalesforceEntityID IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SalesforceEntity] sfe on sfe.ID = sub.SalesforceEntityID 
ORDER BY leg.LegalEntityName
```

Query itself is working properly and results that I am receiving are expected. I just need to enumerate this exact output.
[First 20 rows output of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRT3D.png)

So far I have tried approaching this with **DENSE_RANK** function, so I will enumerate each unique ID row with RowCounter, and specify in where function to **rowcounter**>**@skip** and **rowcounter**<**@take**+**@skip**.

My problem with this approach was that to make **DENSE_RANK** work I need to order my query by **leg.ID**, but my data needs to be displayed with **leg.LegalEntityName** ordering. And if I will order data by
**leg.LegalEntityName** in the end, RowCounter will be all over the place [query with DENSE_RANK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AucK8.png)

And if I do `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY leg.LegalEntityName) AS RowCounter` rowcount is not counting properly [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGp41.png)

Is this the best approach to solve this issue? And if it is how to use **DENSE_RANK** so it wont screw my ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I call this: you can't sort on two things at the same time.

If you want pagination to be by ID, but output after pagination to be in LegalEntityName order, nothing should stop you:

```sql
select *
from (
  select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS paging
  from sometable s
) x
where x.paging between 1 and 20
order by someothercolumn
```

This creates paging column, and then takes the first "page" ordered by something completely different